# If there is multiple file written in different languages, how to compile into one file?

Tags: javascript, python, haskell, compilation, executable

I have a Haskell program that calls another javascript file and another python file. I can compile each one of them into an executable. But I am interested in compiling all of them into one file. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you compile a Javascript file into an executable?

Comment: Good luck with that.  Probably easier to rewrite them to be in one language.

Comment: @nnnnnn http://enclosejs.com/ enclosejs is a javascript compiler

Comment: What does "calls" mean here exactly?

Comment: Maybe you can use the Haskell FFI to provide access (import/export) of C-level bindings. If your compiler can produce object files with C-level bindings, you can use a linker to link them together (and link the Haskell/js runtime too). You will probably need to write export/import code in both languages. Overall, it looks quite tricky -- a lot of work, with no real guarantee on the result.